# How to join two pandas data frames

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas data frames:

```
df1
    id frid title
    1  1    abc
    2  1    ddd
    3  2    ghc
    4  3    frg
    5  1    def

df2
    frid comment
    1    w
    2    s
    3    e
```

Now I want to merge these two data frames based on the field `frid`. In other words, I want to add column `comment` to `df1`. How can I do this? I know about `join` command, but it works differently (`df1.join(df2)`).

The result should be:

```
df
    id frid title comment
    1  1    abc   w
    2  1    ddd   w
    3  2    ghc   s
    4  3    frg   e
    5  1    def   w
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) and pass the column you want to merge on, by default this performs an 'inner' merge:

```
In [198]:
df1.merge(df2, on='frid')

Out[198]:
   id  frid title comment
0   1     1   abc       w
1   2     1   ddd       w
2   5     1   def       w
3   3     2   ghc       s
4   4     3   frg       e
```